Error starting a Medusajs project on the server
I started a brand new Medusajs project and it works perfectly locally, but I tried to deploy it to a Dokku server (only the API with the admin, I didn't try to storefront yet), and it does not start.
I managed to reproduce the same error I am seeing on the server by running with NODE_ENV production locally:
NODE_ENV=production yarn start

It builds with no errors, but then it crashes:
➜  backend git:(enable-redis) ✗ NODE_ENV=production yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ cross-env yarn build && medusa start
$ cross-env yarn clean && yarn build:server && yarn build:admin
$ cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist
$ cross-env yarn clean && tsc -p tsconfig.server.json
$ cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist
$ cross-env medusa-admin build

✔ Webpack
  Compiled successfully in 19.94s

{"level":"error","message":"Error starting server","stack":[{"columnNumber":15,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/config.js","functionName":"errorHandler","lineNumber":23,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":9,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/config.js","functionName":null,"lineNumber":45,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":57,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":null,"lineNumber":268,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":23,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":"step","lineNumber":56,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":53,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":"Object.next","lineNumber":37,"methodName":"next","native":false,"typeName":"Object"},{"columnNumber":71,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":null,"lineNumber":31,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":null,"fileName":null,"functionName":"new Promise","lineNumber":null,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":12,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":"__awaiter","lineNumber":27,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":12,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/loaders/index.js","functionName":null,"lineNumber":262,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null},{"columnNumber":72,"fileName":"/Users/artur/projects/enigma/liderpav/backend/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/start.js","functionName":null,"lineNumber":66,"methodName":null,"native":false,"typeName":null}],"timestamp":"2024-04-17 10:51:17"}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

What am I missing? The logs are not very helpful
I am trying to deploy the API and the admin of a MedusaJS project to a server using Dokku, but it is not starting.

Is it possible your medusa app doesn't have the correct environment variables to start? Like maybe missing a postgres connection string or similar: https://github.com/medusajs/medusa/issues/3857

To make sure of that, I changed the NODE_ENV to development and deployed the app, and with that, everything worked. I don't quite understand what is going on

Its possible that when NODE_ENV=production, there are other environment variables (like a secret key) that are required for running. I would consult the medusa docs to see if they have anything around production deployment.

honeslty i only use the pure .env for production it could be bad practice but i found it hustle free that being said
as far as i know  if you use the the NODE_ENV=production your  .env file should be .env.production .
